# How to make trimmer sound less

Tags: sound

I got new baby boy and in our religion we shave baby hair. I was thinking of using trimmer but as trimmer has loud sound. What can be a better way to make the sound of trimmer less? So the child don’t feel it is loud.

Comment: Congratulations, Nofel. We wish you and your family much health and happiness.

Comment: Does the noise change if you grip the trimmer tightly? (possible due to vibration of parts inside the trimmer case)

Comment: **CAUTION**: Take great care. Electric trimmer blades are sharp and have enough space between the blades to catch a fold of baby's thin skin causing injury. Friction heats the trimmer blades enough to cause some discomfort to sensitive skin in contact.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching any weighted material to the vibrating trimmer will help to diminish the noise level. Temporarily, you could use one or more thick elastic bands or tape around the trimmer handle to attach extra weight with something of convenient size. Tight bands or tape around the handle might be enough to help cut the noise without the added mass. You will be the best judge for what works.

On the other side of the problem is the added difficulty of holding and controlling the larger, heavier object near a young child. Also, try to avoid making the machine into something scary and threatening—use bright colourful alterations rather than a mechanical monster creation.

An adult can hold still and has enough physical self-control to resist the hair-cutter's motions; but, a child can move unexpectedly to make control of an electric device for precise work difficult. You will probably want another to help you.

Children are unpredictable. Take your time. Some children might enjoy the unusual humming of the clipper if accompanied by a story, funny actions, or pictures for diversion. Even with help, the experience might be difficult for another child for reasons having little to do with the trimmer noise.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The electric hair trimmer I use has an adjustment screw. The idea is to run the screw in until the trimmer becomes noisy, and then back off the screw to where it goes quieter. It also has a set of plastic spacers so the vibrating cutter does not touch the skin.

Or you could use a non-electric hair trimmer, such as these hand clippers and safety razor comb:

[image]

Comment: Nostalgic the hand clipper. Never saw it since my teenage